# zip two lists produced by two functions (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have two functions (count and listOfNths) that both take parameters and produce a list. I would like to zip the the lists produced by these two functions. How would I go about doing that?
I tried writing `zip listOfNths count` but that didn't work.

```
count n = [ x | x <- [0..n-1]]

everyf n [] = []
everyf n as  = head as : everyf n (drop n as)
listOfNths :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
listOfNths n xs = map (\x -> everyf n (drop x xs)) [0..n-1]
```

just a sidenote: the function listOfNths makes use of another function (everyf) but that's not important.

Comment: A sidenote, `[x | x <- ys]` is equivalent to just `ys`, so `count n = [0..n-1]` would suffice.

Comment: I think what you're wanting to do is `\n xs -> zip (listOfNths n xs) (count n)`.  This would typecheck, but is a function in itself.  You're running into issues here because `zip` wants both of its inputs to be lists, but both `listOfNths` and `count` are functions that return lists.  You need to supply these with input before you'll be able to zip them together.

Comment: ``fn n xs = (`zip` [0..n-1])  . transpose . chunksOf n $ xs``. `chunksOf` is in [`Data.List.Split`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this using a simple `map`:

```
fn n xs = map (\x -> (everyf n $ drop x xs, x)) [0..n-1]
```

If you insist on using a zip, then you have to evaluate the functions prior to zipping:

```
fn n xs = zip (listOfNths n xs) (count n)
```